# Trouble setting up cert-manager without helm or rbac on gke

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I believe I have followed this guide:
https://medium.com/@hobochild/installing-cert-manager-on-a-gcloud-k8s-cluster-d379223f43ff

which, has me install the `without-rbac` version of cert-manager from this repo:
https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager

however when the cert-manager pod boots up it starts spamming this error:
`leaderelection.go:224] error retrieving resource lock cert-manager/cert-manager-controller: configmaps "cert-manager-controller" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:default" cannot get configmaps in the namespace "cert-manager": Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:default"`

Hoping someone has some ideas.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it works great. Turns out I needed to set it up with RBAC. Maybe the guide was old. You need to install with RBAC, which is what that error was telling me, just as james said below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the 'with-rbac.yaml' variant if you are installing in GKE, unless you have explicitly disabled RBAC on the GKE cluster!

This should resolve the issues you're seeing here, as by the looks of your error message, you *do* have RBAC enabled!

Answer (score 1):

The errors seem to be coming from RBAC.  If you're running this in `minikube` you can grant the `default` service account in the `cert-manager` namespace the proper rights by running:

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding cert-manager-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=cert-manager:default`

After creating the role binding, `cert-manager` should complete its startup.